# Qt: c++: How to create a SIGNAL/SLOT when selecting a row in QTableView

Tags: c++, qt, model, qtableview

I have a `QTableView` which is working properly showing my model on the GUI. however, I would like to create a "SIGNAL/SLOT" that works when I select a row from the `QTableView`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 6):

You can do it in this way:

```
connect(ui->tableView->selectionModel(), SIGNAL(selectionChanged(const QItemSelection &, const QItemSelection &)),
             SLOT(slotSelectionChange(const QItemSelection &, const QItemSelection &))
            );
```

And the slot would be:

```
void MainWindow::slotSelectionChange(const QItemSelection &, const QItemSelection &)
{
            QModelIndexList selection = ui->tableView->selectionModel()->selectedRows();//Here you are getting the indexes of the selected rows

            //Now you can create your code using this information
}
```

I hope this can help you.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `currentRowChanged(const QModelIndex & current, const QModelIndex & previous)` signal from the selection model ([docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qitemselectionmodel.html#currentRowChanged)).

Answer (score 2):

See the documentation QAbstractItemView [https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.7/qabstractitemview.html](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.7/qabstractitemview.html#signalSection)

> void QAbstractItemView    **activated** (const QModelIndex  &index ) [signal]
>
> This signal is emitted when the item specified by index is activated
> by the user. How to activate items depends on the platform; e.g., by
> single- or double-clicking the item, or by pressing the Return or
> Enter key when the item is current.

And use QModelIndex::row()

Comment: Activation is not the same as selection.